# Trying to run vNext in VS2015 RC

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I try to run some benchmarking projects that Microsoft have created for ASP.NET vNext but get some compile errors related to the framework. Google didnt help me. What do I need to do to get everything running?

[image]

Comment: At a glance, it appears to me that .NET 5 Core didn't get installed properly.

Comment: is there a setup somewhere? or is it just nuget packages? do I need to compile the git repo?

Comment: Looks to me like installing VS is supposed to do it for you, but you might dive into some of the deeper details at https://github.com/aspnet/home.

Comment: I've double checked the vstudio install package, there is no extra options for it.

Answer (score 2):

Run the DNVM upgrade command.

[image]

1. Goto `C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX`
2. Run `dnvm upgrade`